# d3 scale depending on nested data

Tags: d3.js, svg, each, axis

I have dataset with 36 countries and it's nested with 6 groups with 6 countries for each group (the countries are on the x axis). I'm making 6 SVGs, one for each group. Because each group has different countries, I'd like to make a different x scale for each group.

I'm trying with `.each` but it doesn't work. Perhaps the use of `.each` was wrong or simply it wasn't a canonical way to do? Do you have better way to do it?

```
var chartsContainer = d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll(".container")
  .data(nest)
  .enter()
  .append("svg")
  .attr("class", "container")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

chartsContainer
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.values;
  })
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "xAxis")
  .each(function(d) {

    xScale.domain(d.map(function(d) {
      return d.country;
    }))
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(xScale)
      .orient("bottom");
    axis(d3.select(this));

  })
```

Comment: Can you add a fiddle for your code

Comment: If you want to have a different x scale for each chart, you need to create a separate scale for each, and you need to store those scales in separate variables. At the moment, you are using `xScale` for all six charts.

Comment: The problem above was mainly due to use of map. The input for map should have been an array instead of object.